# What is the best way to get all eloquent model instances meeting multiple requirements inside different relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have multiple `Orders` which have related `Payments` and related `InvoiceCorrections`.

I want to fetch all orders where the

order->payments->sum('amount')`differs from`(order->amount - order->invoiceCorrections->sum('amount')).

What would be the best way to archive this, while keeping a good performance?

Answer (score 1):

The payments should have their own column containing correction information which gets updated via a model observer, otherwise your queries are going to get very complex and messy very fast.

Comment: i would like to keep payments as they are. A customer can make and receive payments without a direct invoiceCorrection relation.